# CLEyeMulticam.dll no where on my system PS3 Eye C#

Tags: c#, dll, camera

I am trying to use the PS3 Eye camera in C# and get the error 
"Unable to load DLL 'CLEyeMulticam.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

when running the sample WinForms application.  That DLL file is not located anywhere on my system.  There is a CLEyeMulticam.lib file in the Lib directory of the install.

Is the installer no longer working?  Can I manually download the dll somewhere or am I just missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, installing the CL Eye Platform Driver (http://codelaboratories.com/downloads/) made this go away.

The 'CLEyeMulticam.dll' is still no where to be found on my computer but oh well.  I would still love to know what caused this error (or what caused it to be fixed when the dll is not present) if anyone happens to understand it.

Comment: jees, CL Eye is pretty much an example of how not to do documentation.  I had the same problem, and reinstalled the Driver, and then it moved to the next error: "Getting number of cameras
(1) Could not find the CLEyeMulticam.dll
(2) Could not find the CLEyeMulticam.dll"

The file definitely is not included in the installation.  What rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that struggle to find CLEyeMulticam.dll, you can find it here : https://codelaboratories.com/?ACT=47&fid=13&aid=157_YuOeYe4kVMWACHcBszBD&board_id=1

and it will located at : C:\Program Files (x86)\Code Laboratories\CL-Eye Platform SDK\Bin